# CXF Web-Services Response return invalid name

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I used CXF WSDL2java to generate a server for an existing WSDL.

This gave me a SEI like that :

```java
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://mon.namespace.1", name = "MonWs")
@XmlSeeAlso({ObjectFactory.class})
public interface MonWs {

    @WebResult(name = "Output", targetNamespace = "http://mon.namespace.1")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "maMethodePrincipale", targetNamespace = "http://mon.namespace.1", className = "MaMethodePrincipaleRequest")
    @WebMethod(operationName = "maMethodePrincipale", action = "http://mon.namespace.1/MonWs/maMethodePrincipale")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "maMethodePrincipaleResponse", targetNamespace = "http://mon.namespace.1", className = "MaMethodePrincipaleResponse")
    public MaMethodePrincipaleResponse.Output maMethodePrincipale(
        @WebParam(name = "Input", targetNamespace = "http://mon.namespace.1")
        MaMethodePrincipaleRequest.Input Input
    );
}
```

I created a basic implementation but when I call it on my server (hosted on tomcat, with de CXfNonSpringServlet) with soapUI (and other client) I got this kind of return :

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns1:MaMethodePrincipaleResponse xmlns:ns1="http://mon.namespace.1">
         <ns2:return xmlns="http://mon.namespace.2" xmlns:ns2="http://mon.namespace.1"/>
            ...
            my return object field list correctly named
            ...
         </ns2:return>
      </ns1:MaMethodePrincipaleResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

my problem is the the tag "ns2:return ..." it should be name "Output" like I define in all the annotations (even in maMethodePrincipaleResponse name etc...)
So when i try to call my server with a java client I've got an error message like

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Unexpected Element (URI : "http://mon.namespace.1", local : "return"). Expected elements are <{http://mon.namespace.1}Output>
```

I already try a bunch of possible correction like set the soap binding to "bare" and set every partname or name to "Output" But nothing works.

What should i do to have this return parameter named "Output"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use Interceptor.

in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915428/how-to-modify-the-raw-xml-message-of-an-outbound-cxf-request) you can see how you can modify cxf response.

good luck

Comment: This seems to be fine, but perhaps too long to set up, if nothing else works, i think i'll end up to do an interceptor.

Comment: I got the same error.I've tried so many ways. this way is long way, but it's work.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Request/ResponseWrapper's.   Thus, the names for the elements would be defined in the annotations on the fields in those classes.

Comment: In my response Wrapper I've got something like this: ` @XmlElement(name = "Output")
protected MaMethodePrincipaleResponse.Output output;`